# mypy error when evaluating return of np.argmin function

Tags: python, numpy, mypy

I have a function that looks as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def test() -> np.ndarray:
    return np.argmin(np.array([1, 2, 3]))
```

According to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) the return type for `np.argmin` is `np.ndarray`, but mypy raises the error `Incompatible return value type (got "integer[Any]", expected "ndarray")`. How do I correctly annotate this function?

Comment: The description in the documentation is not quite accurate. It can also return a single integer, as shown in the examples.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Annotating the return of this function as ´Union[int, Sequence[int]]´ still returns the error that this function resulted in ´"integer[Any]"´, but that doesn't take into account that it could also be an array does it?

Answer (score 0):

If the array you pass is 1D (shape is `(X,)`), `np.argmin` returns the index of the smallest value in that array.. For `[1,2,3]`, obviously, the lowest value is `1` at index `0`; thus `np.argmin` will return zero:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> np.argmin(a)
0
```

It's similar to `np.argmax`, which returns the index of the *largest* value in the specified array:

```
>>> np.argmax(a)
2
```

If the array you pass it has more complex dimensions (i.e., is not just a flat list), *and* you pass the `axis` parameter, `np.argmin` will return a copy of the array you pass it, except, for each array containing only numbers, that array will be replaced with the index of the smallest value in that array. For example:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                  [6, 5, 4]])
>>> np.argmin(a, axis=1)
array([0, 2])
```

You need to annotate your method to return `np.integer`, which is what `argmin` is annoted to return:

```
import numpy as np

def test() -> np.integer:
    return np.argmin(np.array([1, 2, 3]))
```